# Entity Framework Intermittent Timeouts On SaveChanges

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

We have been getting intermittent timeouts on calling `SaveChanges` with Entity Framework, I decided to turn on the `Database.Log` on `DbContext` to try and work out what was going on, the output was as follows:

```
Opened connection at 5/9/2015 4:56:57 PM +00:00

Started transaction at 5/9/2015 4:56:57 PM +00:00

UPDATE [Search].[IndexingStatuses]
SET [DateTimeLastUpdated] = @0, [IndexStores_IndexStoreId] = @1
WHERE ([CustomerId] = @2)

-- @0: '5/9/2015 4:03:57 PM' (Type = DateTime2)

-- @1: '2' (Type = Int16)

-- @2: '1' (Type = Int32)

-- Executing at 5/9/2015 4:56:57 PM +00:00

-- Completed in 1 ms with result: 1

Failed to commit transaction at 5/9/2015 4:57:13 PM +00:00 with error: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

Closed connection at 5/9/2015 4:57:13 PM +00:00
```

This is very strange, it's a simple update and as you can see the transaction is started at 4:56:57, the update takes 1 ms but for some reason there is a timeout at 4:57:13 which is only 16 seconds later which is less than our timeout limit anyway.

Does anyone know why we are intermittently getting these?

Comment: Are you using a TransactionScope?

Comment: No transaction scope

Comment: Hmm. Would need to see the code to have any clue about what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say surely but it seems your server is running on a very less free memory. One of the following things may work for you -

1. Incresing Timeout for a larger value once. Possibly query will not take that much time when it will run for second time as it will already have execution plan.
2. Delete transaction logs, tempDb data.
3. Use filter condition in your query to update smaller set of data at a time.